# How to install Flask offline?

Tags: python, flask

I've downloaded Flask on my pc, then I'm disconnected, now I need to install Flask without internet connection. What else I need to install Flask offline and in which order should I install them?

Comment: You can install [bottle](https://bottlepy.org/), which at time of writing has no dependencies. Might be worth considering if you have not yet developed your application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to download all of flask's dependencies:

- Werkzeug>=0.7
- Jinja2>=2.4, which requires:

  - MarkupSafe
  - Babel>=0.8, which requires:

    - pytz
- itsdangerous>=0.21
- click >= 2.0

Install them in that order before you install Flask.

You can install the downloaded packages in several ways, the easiest is to use [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/), which you then also need to download and install first if you don't already have it. Then you just do

```
pip install ThePackageFile-0.0.0.tgz
```

If you don't have pip installed on the target machine, you can expand the archive and then run the `setup.py` script:

```
tar xvzf ThePackageFile-0.0.0.tgz
# .. some output
python ThePackageFile/setup.py install
```

Comment: I believe that you have misunderstood the question entirely. To quote the OP -> "I've downloaded Flask on my pc, then I'm disconnected, now I need to install Flask without internet connection"

Comment: Read his last sentence.

Comment: But you haven't shown him how to install flask offline.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Well, he has really. Assuming you know how to install a downloaded package, which is quite trivial if you know how to install a non-downloaded package.

Comment: Anyway, I added that.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Thanks for that. Downvote rescinded.

Comment: Just "pip download flask". You should end up with:

  # ls
  click-6.6.tar.gz                 Jinja2-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Flask-0.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl  MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz
  itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz         Werkzeug-0.11.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Comment: As [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1540468/paul-rooney) pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764655/install-python-flask-without-using-pip), you need also [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).